# Copy and rename PHP script

Tags: php, date, copy, rename

i'm making a script that copies a file to another direction and renames it in there with a date stamp. This is what I got so far:

```
<?php

copy('test.xlsx', 'date/test.xlsx');


$filename = 'date/test.xlsx';

if (file_exists($filename)) {
    $date = new DateTime();
    rename("date/test.xlsx", "date/test " . $date->format('Y-m-d') . ".xlsx");
    echo "Rename done";
} else {
    echo "File not found";
}
?>
```

It gives me a error cant find script.php (line 15)
Line 15: `rename("date/test.xlsx", "test " . $date->format('Y-m-d') . ".xlsx");`
I don't know whats wrong because its the first time in PHP for me i looked on the internet for it but cant find it so i hope you guys can help me out.
Thanks.

Comment: can you pls paste what the error you see on screen

Comment: What is your goal? What do you want to rename to what?

Comment: Does the 'date' folder already exist? Do you have writing permissions on it?

Comment: it looks like you are checking if a file exists and using another one

Comment: The goal it to copy the file to another directory and renames it in that directory to the name + date.xlsx. I'll upload the error in 1 minute.

Comment: http://i61.tinypic.com/vgh21l.png error its in dutch but it says: Warning: rename(date/test.xlsx,Dusseldorp 2015-04-01.xlsx): The system can't find the file: (code: 2) in C:\xampp\htdocs\stage\script.php on line 15

Comment: I think file "date/test.xlsx" doesn't exists...you check existence of 'text.xlsx' and try rename "date/test.xlsx"; which is not existing

Comment: @FrankWinters You check if file: `test.xlsx` exists, but then you use `date/test.xlsx`, so this is obviously not going to work!

Comment: just edited it to date/test.xlsx

Comment: You just make a big mess you have file, new file and then again filename, so it's very unclear what you want to do! Please add an example: `$fileXY -> $fileXYZ`

Comment: He is new to PHP so he doesn't know, first error is fixed now it says file not exitst so its not coping the file to the other directory

Comment: And what doesn't work now? What is the problem now, do you get any errors? The error in your question doesn't match with your code

Comment: Yes Rizier123, you helpt me out the code is working fine now thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i edited your file with the help of the comments from rizier and made it a file.

```
<?php

copy('test.xlsx', 'date/test.xlsx');


$filename = 'date/test.xlsx';

if (file_exists($filename)) {
    $date = new DateTime();
    rename("date/test.xlsx", "date/test " . $date->format('Y-m-d') . ".xlsx");
    echo "Rename done";
} else {
    echo "File not found";
}
?>
```

Answer is made by razier i only pasted in the file so you can use it.

Answer (score 3):

```
copy ('test.xlsx', 'date/test_' . date('Y-m-d') . '.xlsx');
```

copies and "renames" in one step. @see http://php.net/copy